# Need to access array after exit from SSH in bash script

Tags: bash, shell-script, ssh, find

I need to access array which is dynamically created.

First look into the code:

```
ssh username@11.22.333.44 <<'ENDSSH'
cd /home/ubuntu/user/someFolder
array=(`find . -name 'something*'`)
len=${#array[*]}

i=0
while [ $i -lt $len ]; do
    let i++
done
echo  "${array[*]}"  #here I can access array values
ENDSSH
#Just above i have exited from ssh & now I need to access array values but not getting.
echo  "${array[*]}" #here I'm unable to get array values
exit
```

My concern is to access array after ENDSSH.

Comment: That array existed in the memory of the shell that ran on the remote host, not in the shell on the local host.

Comment: @AndyDalton So is there any way by which I can access outside remote host?

Comment: You are constructing array on the remote host.  You'll need to transmit the data back to the local host.  Probably the easiest thing to do is to serialize it and write it to stdout, then have the script that is invoking ssh read the output stream.

Comment: @WilliamPursell If you can provide any sample code or something will be best for me. However I can not do scp from remote host to my local as scp needs public ip.

Comment: What are you wanting to do with those pathnames? If you want to do something with them on the remote host, don't turn them into a string and send them back and forth, just run whatever you need to run on the remote host with `find` directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're comfortable using backticks and `find` to construct the array, you clearly aren't worried too much about serializing the data robustly (for example, whitespace in the output of `find` is going to be split into distinct element of the array, which may not be desired), so just do:

```
array=($( ssh username@11.22.333.44 sh -c "find . -name 'something*'"))
```

and build the array on the local host.

Comment: I think ssh runs a shell anyway, so you don't need the `sh -c`

Comment: sh -c "cmd" makes it easier to understand the quoting.  `ssh user@host cmd with "quoted string"` runs cmd with "quoted" and "string" as separate, unquoted arguments.  `ssh user@host sh -c "cmd with 'quoted string'"` runs the command as expected.  `ssh user@host "cmd with 'quoted string'"` I believe is exactly the same, but IMO looks really weird.  YMMV.  Including `sh -c` is purely a style thing.

Comment: But I need to run change directory after ssh username@11.22.333.44 and need to find.

Comment: You don't actually need to cd.  You can just as easily do `find /home/ubuntu/user/someFolder`, or you can do `sh -c 'cd ..; find . ...'`

Comment: @WilliamPursell  Worked! Really appreciated alot.

Comment: you probably want `cd ... && find ...` instead of `cd ... ; find ...`

Comment: @ShubhamKumarRohit, if it worked, do not forget to accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

From [one of your comments](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/453236/need-to-access-array-after-exit-from-ssh-in-bash-script#comment823441_453236), it sounds as if what you're intending to do is to create a list of pathnames of files that you'd like to transfer from the remote system to the local machine using `scp`. The issue with this is that you passing pathnames back and forth between the two systems which introduces the risk that filenames that includes whitespace characters may be mangled.

If you're looking for a way to transfer all the files that matches `something*` from somewhere under `/home/ubuntu/user/someFolder` on the remote machine, you may use `rsync` like this:

```
rsync -av --include='*/' --include='something*' --exclude='*' \
    --prune-empty-dirs \
    username@11.22.333.44:/home/ubuntu/user/someFolder/ ./target
```

This would find and transfer all files matching the pattern and the directory structure that they live in to the local machine under the path `./target`.

The `--include` and `--exclude` patterns are applied from left to right and the first match is what matters:

- `--include='*/'`: Look into all subdirectories (empty directories, i.e. directories with no matching filenames, are not transferred due to `--prune-empty-dirs`).
- `--include='something*'`: The pattern that would match the things we're actually interested in.
- `--exclude='*'`: Ignore everything else.